# Exponents and square roots as user input

Tags: c++, input

How can I allow the user to enter a number in the form of e^x, or sqrt(x) when asked, instead of just entering a number in numerical form? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to [parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the input. Chances are your grammar will be very simple, so the parsing can be done very easily. Read the input as a string, check the format is valid, and interpret the string as a value depending on its format.

Comment: Would the input always be a number, of the form e^x, or of the form sqrt(x), or would other inputs be possible as well?

Comment: If you could show us what you're trying now that isn't working, we can help with that.  If you're completely stuck and have no idea where to even begin, then give it a think and some experimentation to find somethign that works.

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither of those two things are numbers. The user inputs a sequence of characters, and you have to interpret them. If they are all numerical you can usually just use something like `atoi (...)` to get the number as a base-10 integer. Anything beyond this is going to involve parsing the input and potentially evaluating nested expressions.

Comment: @templatetypedef the user enters mainly decimal numbers (e.g. 0.1234567), but there are some cases where (for their own convenience) can enter a number of the aforementioned forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is a question of parsing. In the case of these two forms exactly, a simple solution could be something like:

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
if (input[0] == 'e' && input[1] == '^') {
  int num = atoi(input.substr(2).c_str());  // probably better to use stringstreams here
  cout << exp(num) << endl;
} else if (input.substr(0, 5) == "sqrt(" && input[input.size() - 1] == ')') {
  int num = atoi(input.substr(5, input.size() - 6).c_str());
  cout << sqrt(num) << endl;
} else {
  cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

Didn't test that but should be roughly right. If you need to handle more nuanced cases or more than just these 2 cases, you'll have to do some more elaborate parsing.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. By the way, you missed .c_str() in the num definition of the else if condition.